# Getting MAX of AVERAGE measure (Power BI/DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am stumped. I am calculating an average of products sold per location. Then, I am using AVERAGEX to calculate that average for each sales associate.

But how do I find the MAX of that average and use that as a benchmark for each associate? I want to know for each associate the difference between the MAX AVERAGE products/location and the associates AVERAGE products/location.

I've wanted to use some sort of summary table, but this is a problem because then I lose the contexts I need (dates, locations with sales in that date period). Below are the measures I have so far:

```
ProductsPerLocation = DIVIDE([TotalSolutions],[TotalLocations])

AveProductsPerLocationByAssociate = AVERAGEX(VALUES(Employees[EmpID]),[ProductsPerLocation])
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to create context aware summary tables in DAX. Please check this article: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/